# Euler Brick imlementation in Java

Tags: java, math, cube, pythagorean

Hello to all who are taking the time out of their day to attempt and help solve my problem. I am truly stuck for the first time in a while and would really appriciate some help. But enough exposition; here is the what I have implemented thus far:

```
public class EulerBrick {

    private int a, b, c;
    private int d, e, f;
    private Random random;

    public EulerBrick(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = (int) Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
        this.e = (int) Math.sqrt((a * a) + (c * c));
        this.f = (int) Math.sqrt((b * b) + (c * c));
        this.random = new Random();

        if (verify(a, b, c, random.nextInt())) {
            if (a % 3 != 0) {
                if (b % 3 != 0) return;
                if (c % 3 != 0) return;
            }
            if (a % 4 != 0) {
                if (b % 4 != 0) return;
                if (c % 4 != 0) return;
            }
            if (a % 11 != 0) {
                if (b % 11 != 0) {
                    if (c % 11 != 0) return;
                }
            }
        } else return;

        printDimensions();
    }

    public boolean verify(double a, double b, double c, int k) {
        a *= k;
        b *= k;
        c *= k;

        if (a % 3 != 0) {
            if (b % 3 != 0) return false;
            if (c % 3 != 0) return false;
        }
        if (a % 4 != 0) {
            if (b % 4 != 0) return false;
            if (c % 4 != 0) return false;
        }
        if (a % 11 != 0) {
            if (b % 11 != 0) {
                if (c % 11 != 0) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void printDimensions() {
        System.out.println("Side A: " + a + ", Side B: " + b + ", Side C: " + c + ", Side D: " + d + ", Side E: " + e + ", Side F: " + f);
    }

}
```

And here is the main class I am using to test it:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while (true) {
            new EulerBrick(i += 3, j += 4, k += 11);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

//      EulerBrick brick = new EulerBrick(44, 117, 240);
    }

}
```

Again any help would be greatly appreciated. Also this isn't for a course/class just an exercise that Ive stumped myself on.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what problem you have, no?  Also, your test code looks very odd.  Why are you looping forever and also creating a new object every time?  A constructor is to initialize an object, not do all of the work in it.  I would re-think this approach.

Comment: The main problem with the constructor is that you try a random int, and if it fails the validation, you just return, leaving the object in an undefined state. I would use the constructor to construct the basic brick, then use a method to test a fourth int against the brick.